# How to fix Notice: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I just learned php to display information on the page, I got an error, please help me .. thanks

**this filepolitik.php**

```
<?php
  include 'koneksi.php';

  $tabel1 = 'isiberita';
  $tabel2 = 'kategori';
  $id=1;

  $hal = $_GET['hal']; //*Error : Notice: Undefined index: hal ???
  //validasi halaman
  if (!isset($_GET['hal'])) {
          $page = 1;
  } else {
    $page = $_GET['hal'];
  }
  //data tampil perhalaman
  $max_result = 2;

  $from = (($page * $max_result) - $max_result);

  //query tampil perhalaman
  $sql=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM  $tabel1,$tabel2 where $tabel1.id_kategori=$id and $tabel1.id_kategori=$tabel2.id_kategori
                    ORDER BY tanggal DESC LIMIT $from,$max_result");
while ($tampil = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{

      $data = substr($tampil['isi'],0,200);
      echo "<div class='box'>";
      echo "<p align='justify'>";
      echo "<img class='gambar' src='$tampil[gambar]' width=150px height=150px align='left' />";
      echo "<font valign='top'>";
      echo "<strong>";
      echo $tampil['judul'];
      echo "</strong>";
      echo $data;

      echo "<a href='index.php?menu=detail_politik&id==$tampil[id_berita]'>  baca lengkap>>>></a>";
      echo "</font></p></div><br>";
}

//total
$total_result = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) as Num From $tabel1 where $tabel1.id_kategori=$id");
//Notice: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int ??
$total_pages = ceil($total_result / $max_result);

echo "<center> piliih Halaman <br />";
//proses link
if ($hal > 1) {
  $prev = ($page - 1);
  echo "<a href=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?menu=politik&hal$prev>
        <-Sebelumnya </a>";
}

//link daftar urutan Halaman
for ($i=1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
        if (($hal)==$i) {
          echo "$i";
        } else {
          echo "<a href=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?menu=politik&hal=$i>$i</a>";
        }
      }
        //link halaman selanjutnya
        if ($hal < $total_pages) {
          $next = ($page + 1);
          echo "<a href=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?menu=politik&hal=$next>Selanjutnya-></a>";
        }

      echo "</center>";

?>
```

I followed the book and this is the original script:

```
$total_result = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as Num From $tabel1 where $tabel1.id_kategori=$id"),0);
```

[image: this Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following lines

```
$total_result = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) as Num From $tabel1 where $tabel1.id_kategori=$id");
$total_pages = ceil($total_result / $max_result);
```

..you are trying to fetch the count, but treating the resulting query-object as the results you want. You'll need to fetch the data before you can use it, as such

```
$total_result = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) as Num From $tabel1 where $tabel1.id_kategori=$id");
$total_result_fetched = $total_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total_pages = ceil($total_result_fetched['Num'] / $max_result);
```

Note the `fetch()` and that the `$total_result_fetched` variable now is an array.

You are also exposed to SQL injections, because you use variables directly in the query. You should use **prepared statements** to protect yourself from that. Table and column names cannot be bound, so those should at least be whitelisted. Using `prepare()` and `execute()`, you can bind the values as shown below

```
$total_result = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) as Num From $tabel1 where $tabel1.id_kategori=:id");
$total_result->execute(["id" => $id]);
$total_result_fetched = $total_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total_pages = ceil($total_result_fetched['Num'] / $max_result);
```

Consult the following topics and documentation

- [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter)
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
- [PHP.net on `PDO::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)
- [PHP.net on `PDO::prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)
- [PHP.net on `PDOStatement::execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Comment: I think you should go over a few of the OP's past questions. Some of them look a lot like the one they posted here. Let's see if they accept this answer.

Comment: No acceptance in that history, so I doubt that, but we'll see. The other questions are related, but they're using `mysql_` instead of PDO. So I guess something changed.

Comment: Something has changed a *few* times ;-)

Comment: @Qirel This works Thank you for helping me, sorry I bother you :-) I have to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

```
//FIX ERROR:  from error object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to number.
```

Try This:

```
$query = $connection->query("SELECT count(*) as Num From tbl_blog");

$num   = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$total_laman  = ceil($num ['Num'] / $per_laman);
```